# Preview android cam in tabhost

Tags: android, camera, preview, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost in my Android application and I want to preview my camera IN one of my tabs.

Thanks

Comment: That's great. What's the question?

Comment: I can't realise it, I'm benneginer in this domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SurfaceHolder in the sub Activity like you would do in a normal activity (lot of example about it) then insert this activity in a tab in the classical way:

```
intent = new Intent(this, PreviewActivity.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("previewtab")
                .setIndicator(getText(R.string.tab_item_preview),
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_preview))
                .setContent(intent));
```